# Saving MethodInfo variable in Unity EditorWindow to Component, var resets on compile

Tags: unity-game-engine, compilation, saving-data, methodinfo, unity3d-editor

I'm trying to save a MethodInfo to a script through an editor window. When I create the script that should remember the method info it works well but whenever unity recompiles, (Run-Time, script has changed or unity restarts) the MethodInfo variable has been reset to null. I've tried serializing the class that saves it and making the MethodInfo a SerializedField,

What happens precisely: I select a Component belonging to a GameObject and a MethodInfo belonging to that component. Then create a new GameObject containing a script that has variables for GameObject, Component & MethodInfo. I then set those variables to the selected vars. Untill now it works. When unity compiles again the GameObject and Component are still saved but the MethodInfo has turned to null.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I totally understand this request. I am at the same point.
I have an Editor where the user types in some values and then generates a game object.
I want to grab the current editor set and store that over in the new GameObject as a component, script or DLL.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Unity will be able to serialize an object of MethodInfo class. And even if it was: as Unity is a cross platform engine, there is no guarantee that an object of MethodInfo, as it was saved in the Editor, will be compatible with an object of MethodInfo as it would exist in the platform specific build.

You will have to store the name of the target method and use that together with Reflection to find the correct method at runtime. If the method is overloaded by signature you'll also have to decide which overload to take at runtime.

Comment: Thanks for the Answer, I figured the same so that is exactly what I did, I don't like those ugly hacks though was hoping for a cleaner solution

Comment: Well, if you want to call methods by means of Reflection, using the features of Reflection is the only reasonable thing to do. Unity uses the exact same mechanics to implement UnityEvents (as used by Unity UI). Maybe they are exactly what you are looking for? If not, please give a bit more detail on what you are trying to accomplish, so people might be able to suggest alternatives.